# fetch all photos from gallery and show it in grid view

Tags: android

i want to fetch all photos from gallery and display it in grid view ..all photos i get but the problem is it will not working smoothly like as gallery too mach mobile hang please give me solution if any one have my code is below.

```
    public class getImageFromGallery extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<String>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};
            Cursor c = null;
            SortedSet<String> dirList = new TreeSet<String>();
            final ArrayList<String> resultIAV = new ArrayList<String>();

            String[] directories = null;

            if (u != null)
            {
                String sortOrder ="_id asc limit 1";
                c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
            }

            if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst()))
            {
                do
                {
                    String tempDir = c.getString(0);
                    tempDir = tempDir.substring(0, tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    try{
                        dirList.add(tempDir);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
                while (c.moveToNext());
                directories = new String[dirList.size()];
                dirList.toArray(directories);

            }

            for(int i=0;i<dirList.size();i++)
            {
                File imageDir = new File(directories[i]);
                File[] imageList = imageDir.listFiles();
                if(imageList == null)
                    continue;
                for (File imagePath : imageList) {
                    try {

                        if(imagePath.isDirectory())
                        {
                            imageList = imagePath.listFiles();

                        }
                        if ( imagePath.getName().contains(".jpg")|| imagePath.getName().contains(".JPG")
                                || imagePath.getName().contains(".jpeg")|| imagePath.getName().contains(".JPEG")
                                || imagePath.getName().contains(".png") || imagePath.getName().contains(".PNG")
                                || imagePath.getName().contains(".gif") || imagePath.getName().contains(".GIF")
                                || imagePath.getName().contains(".bmp") || imagePath.getName().contains(".BMP")
                                )
                        {



                            String path= imagePath.getAbsolutePath();
                            resultIAV.add(path);

                        }
                    }
                    //  }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

           ShareMoment.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    shareMomentAdapter  = new ShareMomentAdapter(ShareMoment.this,resultIAV);
                    sharemomentList.setAdapter(shareMomentAdapter);
                }
            });

            return resultIAV;

        }
    }

public class ShareMomentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShareMomentAdapter.ShareMomentViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> shareMomentList;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream;

    public ShareMomentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> shareMomentList) {
        this.shareMomentList = shareMomentList;
//        shareMomentList = new ArrayList<>();
//        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//            shareMomentList.add("" + i);
//        }
        this.context = context;
        bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public ShareMomentAdapter.ShareMomentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_sharemoments, parent, false);


        return new ShareMomentViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ShareMomentAdapter.ShareMomentViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(shareMomentList.get(position));
        final Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, 150, 150, true);

        Glide.with(context).load(shareMomentList.get(position)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).crossFade().into(holder.shareMomentImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shareMomentList.size();
    }

    public class ShareMomentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.shareMomentImage)
        ImageView shareMomentImage;
        //        @Bind(R.id.nameTextview)
//        TextView nameTextview;
//        @Bind(R.id.descriptionTextView)
//        TextView descriptionTextView;
        private View view;

        public ShareMomentViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }


    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, false);

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `runOnUiThread` . Instead override `onPostExecute` which gets triggered once the `doInBackground` finishes it's job and sends back the result to the `onPostExcecute`

Comment: You shouldn't loads all photos at one time. Try to load 10 photos at one time, when user scrolls down than load next 10 photos and so on

Comment: Use an image loader like Picasso or Glide, which will handle the caching and asynchronous loading for you.

Comment: I have already  used  glide for load image in adapter since it will load

Answer (score 0):

Try using LoadMoreView instead of loading all images at once. Load 10-20 images at a time, and then load more when user scrolls down. This will save a lot of memory.

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView